# I can't access VPS Centos after change ssh port 22 to 2222

Tags: linux, centos, vps, plesk, centos6.5

After change ssh port from 22 to 2222, I can't access into VPS.

How can I change port back to 22?

Centos 6.5, Plesk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login to the machine somehow to change the port... how did you change the port? Do you have firewall that blocks connections on 2222? I assume you specified port `ssh -p2222` to connect to?

Comment: I change port to 2222. Then I restart. I logout and login with new port 2222 but unsuccess. May be 2222 was blocked. I don't know what to do. Please help

Comment: Use nmap and scan your host to check if port 2222 is open and sshd is listening. If not, you need to disable firewall and try again.

Comment: Thanks, how can I disable firewall? I can access Plesk

Comment: So login to Plesk, access root and change the port. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks you alot! I use Plesk 12.5.30, so where I can change port?

Comment: I scan VPS with nmap and I don't see port 2222. Port 22 is closed

Comment: @ĐinhVănKiệt I havent used Plesk for years now, there is a tool that allows you to login to shell as root from web-browser. It will give you same permissions as doing ssh and login on root. Search for terminal/emulator/shell...